# Открытие свернутого приложения при получении push-уведомления Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

можно ли реализовать открытие свернутого приложения (без нажатия на само уведомление), при получении push-уведомления (Firebase)? Например: Сервер посылает уведомление о новом заказе курьеру, и у курьера при получении push-уведомления - открывается окно с заказом.

Comment: Полагаю, что это сделать нельзя, в противном случае как минимум 100 вирусов уже открыли бы у вас по 100 окон.